# Custom Flink sink invoked but with no data

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am tying to implement a custom sink, where I created a stubbed invoke function that just logs received data to the task log file (for now) as shown below.

```
package io.name.package;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class AlertSink extends RichSinkFunction<Alert> {
    Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlertSink.class);

    @Override
    public void invoke(Alert alert, Context context) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Invoking sink for alert: ", alert.toString());
    }
}
```

I have configured data steam as shown below.

```
        DataStream<Alert> result = filteredMetrics
            .keyBy(
                new KeySelector<Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, Object>, Tuple3<String, String, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public  Tuple3<String, String, String> getKey(Tuple7<String, String, String, String, String, String, Object> in) throws Exception {
                        return Tuple3.of(in.f0, in.f1, in.f2);
                    }
            })
            .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(10), Time.seconds(5)))
            .process(new ThresholdEvaluator());

        result.addSink(new AlertSink());
```

When, i checked the logs, I see the sink was invoked but showing empty string. ThresholdEvaluator emits the Alert, but showing non-empty string.

```
2020-08-05 19:38:16,638 INFO  io.name.package.AlertSink                      - Invoking sink for alert:
2020-08-05 19:38:16,638 INFO  io.name.package.ThresholdEvaluator             - Alert: {"thresholdID":"123123123","grouping":"svc-platform-5445135-production-graph-service-account-toke644zm","period":"5m","isActive":true,"status":"new","firstSeen":1596656296638,"lastSeen":1596656296638,"count":1}
2020-08-05 19:38:16,640 INFO  io.name.package.AlertSink                      - Invoking sink for alert:
2020-08-05 19:38:16,640 INFO  io.name.package.ThresholdEvaluator             - Alert: {"thresholdID":"123123123","grouping":"svc-platform-5445135-staging-input-service-account-token-q57xf","period":"5m","isActive":true,"status":"new","firstSeen":1596656296640,"lastSeen":1596656296640,"count":1}
2020-08-05 19:38:16,643 INFO  io.name.package.AlertSink                      - Invoking sink for alert:
2020-08-05 19:38:16,643 INFO  io.name.package.ThresholdEvaluator             - Alert: {"thresholdID":"123123123","grouping":"svc-platform-5445135-restructure-repo-cmi-service-account-k76cd","period":"5m","isActive":true,"status":"new","firstSeen":1596656296643,"lastSeen":1596656296643,"count":1}
2020-08-05 19:38:16,646 INFO  io.name.package.AlertSink                      - Invoking sink for alert:
2020-08-05 19:38:16,646 INFO  io.name.package.ThresholdEvaluator             - Alert: {"thresholdID":"123123123","grouping":"svc-integrations-14361530-demo-slack-token","period":"5m","isActive":true,"status":"new","firstSeen":1596656296645,"lastSeen":1596656296645,"count":1}
```

Am I missing something here?

I also tried adding map function in between ThresholdEvaluator and addSink operators. MapFunction seems able to receive Alert object fine but not AlertSink.

```
        result.map(new MapFunction<Alert, Alert>() {
            @Override
            public Alert map(Alert value) {
                LOG.info(value.toString());
                return value;
            }
        }).addSink(new AlertSink());
```

(updated with additional log)

Comment: If instead of `result.addSink(new AlertSink())` you use `result.print()`, do you get results that aren't empty? I'm wondering if the problem is somewhere else, such as the `ThresholdEvaluator`.

Comment: I did not try result.print(), but from ThresholdEvaluator i also log output alert right before emitting output as shown below. 


`2020-08-05 19:38:16,646 INFO  io.name.package.ThresholdEvaluator             - Alert: {"thresholdID":"123123123","grouping":"svc-integrations-14361530-demo-slack-token","period":"5m","isActive":true,"status":"new","firstSeen":1596656296645,"lastSeen":1596656296645,"count":1}`

Comment: I've updated the question with ThresholdEvaluator log, which logs emitted output (Alert).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the AlertSink, so I remain suspicious of the `ThresholdEvaluator`.

Comment: Really strange. I tried inserting MapFunction between ThresholdEvaluator and addSink operator. The MapFunction is able to receive Alert object fine but still not AlertSink.

Comment: @DavidAnderson It turned out it was just a syntax error on my LOG.info. This `LOG.info("Invoking sink for alert: ", alert.toString());` should have read `LOG.info("Invoking sink for alert: " + alert.toString());`. But thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the log output does not have a placeholder to interpolate the value - the right syntax is

```
LOG.info("Invoking sink for alert: {}", alert.toString());
```

The difference between this and

```
LOG.info("Invoking sink for alert: " + alert.toString());
```

is that in a latter case the string concatenation will occur every time regardless of log level, and in first case it will interpolate the value if only the log level is at least `INFO`.